# What is the unit of radius in google maps flutter

Tags: flutter, geometry, google-maps-flutter

I have some markers and circles in my app but I cannot configure... what is the unit of radius inside google_maps_flutter package.. here is part of my code

```
Circle circleA = Circle(
  circleId: CircleId("A"),
  center: LatLng(..., ...),
  radius: 4000, what is unit of radius here.. miles or pixels?
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not used flutter but google map api(s) should follow same standard on all platforms. And basis on this assumption, it should be meter.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/directions#UnitSystem

Answer (score 0):

Hovering over the radius parameter gives you a hint. When I do that, it gives me that it is in meters. Hope it answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is documented on the `Circle` class.

It specifies "meters" in the [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Circle-class.html). Do not refer to the javascript reference, or any other libraries, really.